# Nimble - expect to equal <0.9602>, got <0.9602>

Tags: swift, testing, quick-nimble

My project is written in Swift 2.0 and I use Quick & Nimble to test my code.

```c
expect(workerSpy.buySharesQuantity).to(equal(0.9602))
```

What I get is expectation failure with error message

```
expected to equal <0.9602>, got <0.9602>
```

Definition of buySharesQuantity

```
var buySharesQuantity: Double = 0.0
```

Does anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `beCloseTo` instead of `equal`

More about it why [here](https://github.com/Quick/Nimble#comparisons)